# I need many dates in ISO8601

Tags: javascript, time, timezone, clock, iso8601

JAVASCRIPT

Hello people how are you doing? I am new to Stackoverflow and new to coding. I finally figured out the code to give me date and time in this format

2020-05-18T14:24-06:00

With seconds and milliseconds too! The milliseconds took me like 30 minutes to figure out to make it 0.000 and 0.010 instead of just 0.0 or 0.01

But I have a working ISO8601 string now.

However whenever I change the timezone it changes it relative to my time not UTC.

I want to have a drop down bar to add as many clocks as you need and I want to set them off of UTC how do you code for this?

2020-05-18T14:24Z, 2020-05-18T14:24+01:00, 2020-05-18T14:24+02:00, 2020-05-18T14:24+03:00,
2020-05-18T14:24+04:00

And I can get the Zulu to ISO String but can I eliminate the milliseconds somehow?

At the moment am just putting the code for the clock then manually adding on the "-05:00" I have 18 lines of code for one clock you guys and girls probably can help shorten it?

Comment: Javascript's Date system is pretty terrible at the moment. There's a proposal for a [Temporal](https://tc39.es/proposal-temporal/docs/index.html) object that should do better. In the meantime, a module like [Luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/) should help quite a bit.

Comment: `I have 18 lines of code` - so you say - personally I don't understand the question - perhaps your code will help explain it

Comment: Hi! And welcome to Stack Overflow!  We'd be happy to help, but unfortunately you haven't provided the necessary details for us to understand what you need.  Please take some time to read [*How do I ask a good question?*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [*How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) from the help center.  Thanks!